# Objective-C: How to view a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

For every object that can have a delegate, there is a corresponding protocol, that declares the messages that the object can send it's delegates. The delegate implements methods from the protocol for events it is interested in.

How can one view the protocol in order to find out what functionality needs to be implemented?

Comment: Other than reading the documentation?

Comment: Using an Xcode, is there a way to reference this information?

Comment: Xcode usually comes with a copy of the documentation (unless you chose not to install it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocols in Objective-C are non-essential, but they are useful; Protocols are usually declared in header (.h) files:

```
@protocol MyAwesomeProtocol

-(void)thisMethodIsRequired;

@optional

-(void)theseMethodsAreOptional;

@end
```

... and are usually used in a couple of places:

1: In an instance variable declaration:

```
@class Foo : Bar
{
    id<MyAwesomeProtocol> someIvar;
}
@end
```

2: In property declarations:

```
@class Foo : Bar
{ }
@property (assign) id<MyAwesomeProtocol> someProperty;

@end
```

3: In code (Try to avoid this, but it's legal):

```
if(...)
{
    [(id<MyAwesomeProtocol>)obj foo];
}
```

If you're using Xcode, you can always command-click a protocol that appears anywhere in your code to jump to the header where that protocol is defined. This is true even of Apple's protocols, since header files are not compiled. Also, the documentation available through Xcode provides additional insight on what methods are required or optional.

Since you can define optional protocol methods, you should always check to see if your delegate -respondsToSelector:@selector(isThisMethodImplemented:), since the language doesn't do this for you.

Also, if you're using Xcode, you can option-click a class in your code to bring up the quick documentation panel, which has an option to go to the full documentation for the class of the object you clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

You can either look at the documentation or view the corresponding header file by Command-clicking the protocol in Xcode (Command-doubleclick in Xcode 3).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the doc the `delegate` property, it is almost all the time defined is `id` type and which protocol it is conforming to : `id <TheProtocolYouLookFor>`.
If not, read down the description and you will find more information about the protocol. Protocol names are also links in general.